# Azure Microsoft Graph API - Subscription - validation request failed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I try to set up a notification for changes in Azure user data (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks).

I send a request from a local client to the Azure Graph API and I have a publicly available server (with SSL) in the payload of the request as notification URL.

Azure now sends a posts request to my server (like in the documentation - exact post request see below) and I try to send the token I got back (like in the documentation). But I always get the following error message "Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter."

Post request from Azure:

`Path: /?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+3b3f9821-ce3f-23d9-879b-00a23f3
Body: is empty`

I tried every part and encoding of the path (like just the request ID or the whole path) but I always get the error message. So whats the right thing to send back?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the validation token you receive **should be treated as an opaque value and returned unchanged** and the error `Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter` is trying to tell you that something changed.

Since the validation token comes to you as a URL query parameter, **make sure you're working with a properly decoded value in your code before returning it**.

Here is the relevant documentation from Microsoft Docs: [Notification endpoint validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation)

```
POST https://{notificationUrl}?validationToken={opaqueTokenCreatedByMicrosoftGraph}
```

[image]

Other requirements(from the same reference):

- response within 10 seconds
- 200 (OK) status code.
- content type must be text/plain.
- body must include the validation token.

**Code Samples**

[ASP.NET MVC Sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample) - Specifically look at the NotificationController.cs file

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Listen()
    {

        // Validate the new subscription by sending the token back to Microsoft Graph.
        // This response is required for each subscription.
        if (Request.QueryString["validationToken"] != null)
        {
            var token = Request.QueryString["validationToken"];
            return Content(token, "plain/text");
        }
```

[Node.js code sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample) - Specifically look at listen.js

```
/* Default listen route */
listenRouter.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let status;
  let clientStatesValid;

  // If there's a validationToken parameter in the query string,
  // then this is the request that Office 365 sends to check
  // that this is a valid endpoint.
  // Just send the validationToken back.
  if (req.query && req.query.validationToken) {
    res.send(req.query.validationToken);
    // Send a status of 'Ok'
    status = 200;
  }
```

Comment: my notification url is PowerAutomate and I don't receive validationToken query string. any idea why subscription doesn't send validationToken?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `validationToken` from the query string with an `HTTP 200` response code. You also have to do that within a few seconds, or the graph will fail the request and your call to create the subscription will fail.

Here is an example of the validation endpoint in ASP.NET Web API 2:

```
public ActionResult<string> Post([FromQuery]string validationToken = null)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Token: '{validationToken}'");
        return Ok(validationToken);
    }
}
```